# Is there something to consider before starting a Tor non-exit Relay at home (100mbit)?

Tags: relays, bridge, performance

I recently increased my link to 1:1 100Mbit/s (down/up) at home. It is an unmetered connection IPv4 only.

I have set up a bridge this morning. But I know little of bridges... I do not know if it could saturate my bandwidth or not even close.

Should a **full-fledged non-exit relay** be of more help, I would be happy to hear what I should consider before switching to one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relay is a way better thing for sure, but - actually - it's always acting as one with ORPort available from outside! To provide a proper bridge you need to rise up an obfuscated bridge with OBFS4, just a plain bridge will be easily detected by remote censors, so it will not have a s big impact as it can make. You have nothing special to consider to run a Tor node - just set it up securely and on able hardware, that's it! A static external IP address is a very handy and a **must**, actually